# How to simplify summation?

Tags: probability, self-study

A company has purchased a policy that will compensate for the loss of revenue due to 
severe weather events.  The policy pays 1000 for each severe weather event in a year 
after the first two such events in that year.  The number of severe weather events per year 
has a Poisson distribution with mean 1.  Calculate the expected amount paid to this company in one year.

Solution:
[image]

I am not sure how they simplified the summation to get 1000(1-2(-2e^-1 - e^-1)). Can someone explain and show some extra work on how they did this?

Comment: Actuarial exams?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only real difficulty is the infinite sum

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (x - 2) \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} $$

As per the hint, let's break this up into

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} - 2 \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} $$

(which is valid provided both sums are finite).
Recall that the PMF of the poisson distribution of rate $\lambda = 1$ is

$$ P(k = x) = \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} $$

So the expected value is

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x P(k = x) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} $$

The solution is taking it as known that this expectation is equal to the rate parameter, so

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} x \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} = 1 $$

As for the other sum, it is equal to the sum of the probabilities constituting the mass function of the poisson

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} P(k = x) $$

Since we have a PMF, this sum must be one.

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} = 1 $$

Altogether

$$ \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} (x - 2) \frac{e^{-1}}{x!} = 1 - 2 \times 1 = -1 $$